# Excel formula to format cell compared to the cell above

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I have numeric data between columns F-N. 
I want to conditionally format cells based on the cells above, using a single formula across the range.

I'm using `=$F$6:$N$6<$F$5:$N$5` as Formula but it only matches the first value and formats the entire selection in the same way.

Comment: See if: `=F6<F5` works for you

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, an explanation of why that's the solution could make a useful answer.

Comment: @SamikSengupta, if you use relative reference instead of Absolute then your formula also Compare Row to Row and highligh specific cells rather than Row!!